# how to scale a Bezier curve (using HTML5 canvas)?

Tags: math, canvas, drawing, bezier

I have a Bezier path stored as an array of several points, which is each an array of coordinates in the form [cp1x,cp1y,cp2x,cp2y,x,y].

I'd like to be able to scale this path up and down to adjust its size, but I don't know the math to do that. I tried applying a coefficient to each of the coordinate values, but that didn't seem to work.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: When you scale, which part of the curve will remain fixed in place, one of the ends or the centre?

Comment: I didn't have anything specific in mind, but I would assume center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard representation, the points **P**, represent actual points in space, so you'd move them around like any other points.  That is to scale them, just multiple everything by you scaling factor: say it's `a`, so that would be `[a*cp1x,a*cp1y,a*cp2x,a*cp2y,a*x,a*y]`, or if you want to scale `x` and `y` separately, you can use different factors for the `x` and `y` components.

Note also that this will scale things relative to the origin `(x=0, y=0)`, so if you don't have any curves at the origin, it can look like a shift.  If you want to negate the effect of this shift you can subtract `Px` and `Py` from the `x` and `y` values respectively, where  `Px` and `Py` is the point you want to not move when scaled, before you do the scaling (and then add it back after you multiple, if you want to).  But if what you want to do is scale an entire canvas, like going from 5x5 inch to 7x7, you'd want to do the multiplication without any shifts (and in this case, by 7./5).

Comment: May I ask if the eq to scale a bezier curve not at origin is:
with moveTo origin of x=5, y=6
let function  f(a, cpX, x) = (a * (x-cpXx))+x
therefore [with dummy values]
[f(a, 1, 5), f(a, 4, 6 ), f(a, 8, 5), f(a, 10, 6), f(a, 14, 5), f(a, 14, 6)]

I am trying to get a series of curves drawn on a context which itself scales to the size of the screen. When the context rescales I would like the curves to scale in place as a percentage (var a in this case) of the screen area. The objects to scale with this format but they move slightly as well.

Comment: I actually meant: f(a, cpX, x) = (a * (x-cpX))+x (took out an extra x from cpX).
Stack overflow won't let me edit my comment.

Comment: @CristianCavalli: I don't fully understand your question/comment.  It would probably be better to ask as a separate question where you can give examples, make edits, etc.